# Is the blue square mean the project read-only?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ IDEA open a java project, there shows a blue square in the project name:

[image]

What's that meaning? and I found I can not edit the project's file, and it also shows `File is read-only`.

if the project is read only, how can I make it become read-write?

My Intellij IDEA version is `2019.1.3`.

my project is decompressed from a `.jar` package.

Comment: plz provide intellij idea versions ......

Answer (score 6):

Blue square means the folder is defined as an Intellij Module.

for more details [jetbrains symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html) 
for [Making Files Read-Only or Writable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/toggling-writable-status.html)

**N.B. - you can not edit  `.class` file by Intellij IDEA. if you try this use [decompilers](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) for convert binary file to source file....then try to edit `.java` file**

Comment: But, you see my project, the file is writable  in my project, but there still is read-only,  if I use `file->read-only` there will pin a small lock on the file signal.